# How to cleanly remove x11?

Tags: xorg

I installed x11 in an attempt to get VNC working. Had problems. Then installed TightVNC.

Is it a problem to run both? Are there potential conflicts?

How can I cleanly uninstall x11? I'm running raspbian and want to simply remove what was installed with x11 and no more.

Answer (score 2):

This answer shows up high in search for google "remove X11 ubuntu" so I thought it would help to update it for Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt purge 'x11-*'
sudo apt autoremove
```

And given I don't like cruft in my tmp folder it doesn't hurt to remove the hidden folders in /tmp/

```
# check to see what files or folders are there
sudo ls -alF /tmp
# remove as needed - for example:
sudo rm -r /tmp/.X11-unix  
sudo rm -r /tmp/.XIM-unix
```

Answer (score 1):

most probably this should do the trick (mind the quotes):

```
sudo apt-get remove -purge 'x11-*'
sudo apt-get autoremove
```